# Disable mouse hover Legend in Highcharts LWC

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, highcharts

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
colors: ['#0072BC', '#BFDAFF', '#DDDF00', '#24CBE5', '#64E572', '#FF9655', '#FFF263', '#6AF9C4'],
credits: { enabled: false },
chart: {
renderTo: 'container',
backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)',
type: 'pie',
margin: [0, 0, 0, 0],
spacingTop: 0,
spacingBottom: 0,
spacingLeft: 0,
spacingRight: 0
},
title: { text: null },
plotOptions: {
pie: {
allowPointSelect: false,
size: '100%',
dataLabels: { enabled: false }
}, legend: {
enabled: true,
align: 'right',
layout: 'vertical',
verticalAlign: 'middle',
symbolRadius: 0
},
},
series: [{
showInLegend: false,
type: 'pie',
name: 'Pie Chart',
data: [
['Mobile', 65], // first half of pie
['Other', 35] // second half of pie
]
}]
});

Now on mouse hover on legend it is giving above error.